# Filtering in R with dplyr by previous amount of days

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter rows for the last thirty days of data.

```
last30
    X Y Z Date
    5 4 3 11/15/2018
    7 6 2 11/3/2018
    1 8 4 10/28/2018
    1 2 8 1/2/2018
    3 2 8 4/2/2018
```

With dplyr, I've tried to run the following; when I do, I get no values returned

```
last30 %>%
  filter(between(Date, today() - days(30), today()))
```

Comment: Hi Luke. You first need to change your character "Date" column to Date class (e.g., using `as.Date`). Then your filter call should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can solve this:

```
last30 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y = c(2,1,5,1,5),
                 date = c("11/15/2018", "11/3/2018", "10/28/2018", "1/2/2018", "4/2/2018"))

last30$date <- as.Date(last30$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

# let's fake the current date to make this example immortal:
now = as.Date("11/15/2018", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# however, you should replace it with:
# now = Sys.Date()

temp <- subset(last30, last30$date > now-30)
```

You first change the date column to have the format you require then you subset on the dataset. It is indicated to use Sys.Date() as current date in R.

Hope this helps.